# How can one make git first parent consistent without rebasing?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm looking for a way to use topic branches to create detailed history (and in progress backup) of feature development and use merge commits onto master as summary descriptions of the feature additions.  Well OK use `--no-ff` on your merges in both directions and that's what you get, right.  The problem arises when you try to push and discover that someone else has already pushed changes to master.

From what I've found your options at this point are (a) rebase your local copy of master 'over' these other changes or (b) merge these changes into your local copy of master, then push.  Option (a), rebasing, is a little tedious and rewrites history in a way that obscures the order of events.  Option (b), normal merge, leads to history graphs that obscure the identity of the topic branches versus the 'mainline' (specifically `git log --first-parent` does not refer to what had been the head of the upstream master).

I'd like to avoid both those outcomes, AND I think only a small (predictable) change is needed.  I *think* the problem is only that git sets the current branch as the first parent of a merge.  When merging two local branches this is what makes sense.  However, when merging the current upstream branch to local this is backward.  So how to know it is the upstream branch?  Well that is what tracking branches are for, right?  You can even assign them using an option named `--set-upstream`.

So...

1. Am I wrong that swapping the order of parents when merging a tracking branch would give a clean history, or am I missing something about how tracking branches are used?
2. How could one force git to use the source branch as the first parent of a merge if it is the tracking branch for the current local branch (in a way that gets distributed to clones of the repo)?

**Edit**

My original starting case for this question was not an explicit topic branch, but a single commit representing a semi-trivial change still worth sharing back to the 'mainline'.  I hoped the solution would extend to changesets developed as multiple steps (an actual topic branch) and that case seemed clearer to describe the intent, so I used that as the description.  Unfortunately, the creation of a merge commit *before* discovering a conflict in pushing complicates matters (as quickly pointed out by @Chris).

I'm still interested in answers to (1) and (2) for this simpler case (and will edit the question if the simpler case can be addressed and I work out how to give proper credit to those who have already answered).

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, but rebasing and merging are the only two primary workflows in Git AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abort the merge and redo it with the new `master`.  Assuming you are on `master` and the push of your merge just failed, you can do something like:

```
$ git reset --hard origin/master  # reset to newly-fetched master
$ git merge topic_branch          # redo the merge
$ git push origin HEAD            # re-push the merge
```

If there were no conflicts in the initial merge then no big deal.  Otherwise you need to redo this work, though.  To avoid this tedium, see [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere).

To your specific questions:

1. Yes, merging the initial merge (your version of `master` that failed to push) into the newly-fetched `master` is cleaner than merging in the other direction, but it still introduces a pointless merge.  Redoing the merge makes for a clearer history.
2. `git merge` merges into the current branch, so just checkout what you want to be the first parent.  To avoid rejected pushes, make sure you pull from `master` just before the merge.

Comment: I do think that reversing the order of the parents when merging from an upstream tracking branch would be an improvement to the clarity of history and an improvement to git's usability.  However as @Chris points out this does not resolve the difficulty of a commit failure after merging a topic branch.